# Convert Blob data from javascript to read using opencv in python

Tags: javascript, python, numpy, opencv, blob

I am using javascript to send the video from a client to a backend server using web socket.I am converting the video as blob files and sending it. The function for converting image to blob is given below.

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var _ia = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        _ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var dataView = new DataView(arrayBuffer);
    var blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: mimeString });
    return blob;
}
```

Now, I need to convert the image received back in python back-end to numpy array and process using opencv. How can I convert Blob to image array in python.

Answer (score 1):

The blob data will be stored in request.body( I am using tornado as web app framework ), with type `bytes`.

```
arr = np.asarray( bytearray( request.body ,'utf-8'), dtype = np.uint8 )
bgr_image = cv2.imdecode( arr, -1 ) # load it as it is
```

This works.

Comment: I am still not getting the image. The arr is giving [195 191 195 ... 191 195 153] and the length of arr is 5718. So bgr_image returns none. I got a different solution using webRTC streaming using aiortc. Which is working perfectly.